# E: Unable to locate package ruby!

Tags: ruby

Got this error message:

```
[sudo] password for saeedeh: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ruby
```

What should I do?

Comment: Check your repository settings - Ruby is packaged as [ruby](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=ruby). What Ubuntu version do you have?

Comment: "Unable to locate" a package that is in the Ubuntu repos (like `ruby`) means that your apt data base is either empty or corrupt. Run `sudo apt update` to populate the apt database, then try installing ruby again.

Comment: First thing is to make sure that you are using one of the [currently supported releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Comment: my ubuntu version 17.04

Answer (score 8):

As @N0rbert said, It probably depends on version of Ubuntu you're working on.
You could test `sudo apt-get update` and then run `sudo apt-get install ruby-full` again.

If above mentioned method fails, you must try other methods. Ruby [official site](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#ruby-install) states:

> There are several ways to install Ruby:
>
> When you are on a UNIX-like operating system, using your system’s **package manager** is the easiest way of getting started. However, the packaged Ruby version usually is not the newest one.
>
> **Installers** can be used to install a specific or multiple Ruby versions. There is also an installer for Windows.
>
> Managers help you to switch between multiple Ruby installations on your system.
>
> And finally, you can also **build Ruby from source**.